# Spring XML equivalent of @EnableAsync

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Is there a way to turn on Spring's Async configuration from XML? All the examples I saw are using programmatic context declaration and use `@EnableAsync`

Is there an XML equivalent for this. In some places I saw `<context:annotation-config />` being used, but this doesn't mention anything about async .

I am using Spring 4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try using this

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: yes i've <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler"/>
 <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1"/>
 <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>

Comment: can you post your servlet.xml file content?

Comment: async wasnt working for me as i'd used them on local method...exported the async logic to a separate component

Comment: you can see a sample here on how to use it

http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.in/2010/05/how-to-implement-simple-task-scheduler.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use something like this

```
 <beans>
     <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" exception-handler="exceptionHandler"/>
     <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="7-42" queue-capacity="11"/>
     <bean id="asyncBean" class="com.foo.MyAsyncBean"/>
     <bean id="exceptionHandler" class="com.foo.MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler"/>
 </beans>
```

According to the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html), this is equivalent to using `@EnableAsync`

Comment: Even though my context declaration is xml based and using componentscan, the beans are programmatic with '@Async'...i think the problem is me using '@async' on local methods

Answer (score 1):

In the annotation based approach you have to have @EnableAsync on the Configuration class. Something like as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="com.spring.sample.demoAsync")
public class SpringAsyncConfig {

}
```

Then you create a component class to have a function that is called Asynchronously. Something like as shown below:

```
@Component
public class AsyncClass {

    @Async
    public Future<String> asyncMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing Thread Async:" +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return new AsyncResult<String>(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

To have the xml equivalent of this approach, you can create a bean in the applicationContext.xml file as shown below:

```
<bean id="AsyncClass" class="com.spring.sample.demoAsync.AsyncClass"/>
```

To call the function asyncMethod() in your flow, you can refer AsyncClass bean from any other bean or service. Below is something that I tried to stitch the flow:

```
<bean id="callingBean" class="comspring.sample.demoAsync.CallingBeanClass">
   <property name="AsyncClassBean" ref="AsyncClass"/>
</bean>
```

It's not necessary to follow this step but is an alternative approach.

In my applicationContext.xml file, I also imported the task schema by using:

```
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd"
```

and then mentioning the executor as a task in the same file:

```
<task:executor id="myexecutor" pool-size="5"  />
```

Now my AsyncClass looks like this without @component annotation.

```
public class AsyncClass {

    @Async("myexecutor")
    public Future<String> asyncMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing Thread Async:" +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return new AsyncResult<String>(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

and then finally invoking the asyncMethod() asynchronously from the CallingBeanClass.