# Async annotation in dependency jar, not starting a new thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a class in dependency jar which has a method annotated with Spring `@Async` and I expect that this method should execute asynchronously in another thread.

Using this class I create a bean in my parent project and wire it to my class which has `@Service` annotation. In that class I call a method which has `@Async` annotation, but as I said, the method does not execute in another thread.

How can I achieve this?

This is the code.

This is my interface class:

```
public interface RequestLoggerService {

    @Async
    void log(HttpServletRequest request, String serviceName, String requestIdentifier, String message, boolean successful);
}
```

This is the implementation class:

```
public class RequestLoggerServiceImpl implements RequestLoggerService {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestLoggerServiceImpl.class);

    private RequestLoggerDao requestLogger;

    @Override
    public void log(HttpServletRequest request, String serviceName, String requestIdentifier, String message, boolean successful) {
        logRequest(request, serviceName, request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/") + 1), requestIdentifier, message, successful);
    }
}
```

Those two classes are packed in a jar which is as dependency used in my parent project. I use this class to create a bean in parent project:

```
<bean id="requestLoggerService" class="com.xyz.service.RequestLoggerServiceImpl">
    <property name="requestLogger" ref="requestLoggerDao" />
</bean>
```

And this bean is then auto-wired in my `@Controller` annotated class:

```
public class ActionsController {

    @Autowired 
    private RequestLoggerService requestLogger;
}
```

Comment: Must be something wrong with the code. Post it.

Comment: Are you using XML configuration or `@Configuration` / spring boot? If the latter, then you may need to add the `@EnableAsync` annotation, see https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401640/spring-xml-equivalent-of-enableasync for XML version

Comment: Well, I'm mixing it a bit, but I have @EnableAsync annotation... When I have the class with async method in my parent project, then everything works fine, as soon as I move it to the jar and initialise the bean from the class in that jar, it doesn't work...

Comment: I have added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @BretC instructions and found the solution. The problem was that I was instantiating the `RequestLoggerService` bean through XML configuration, but used annotation @EnableAsync to enable @Async annotation discovery.

This cant be done, either I need to use annotation driven bean creation, or to enable asynchronous tasks in XML configuration.