# Virtual Threads in Spring MVC in Non-Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, virtual-threads

Has anyone got virtual threads working in a non-Spring Boot application with Spring MVC? We have no issues getting it to work when using a task scheduler for scheduled tasks, but we cannot get request controller methods (e.g. methods annotated with @GetMapping, @PostMapping, etc.) to use them. The environment we are using is Spring 6.1 (using XML configuration), Java 21, Tomcat 10.1.18.

We have defined a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, which we use with a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and works fine for scheduled tasks:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
    <property name="virtualThreads" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

The method that we are using to determine if virtual threads are being used is:

```
Thread.currentThread().isVirtual()
```

The following is our Tomcat server.xml file configuration related to virtual threads:

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPoolVirtual" class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardVirtualThreadExecutor"/>

<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           redirectPort="8443"
           maxPostSize="-1"
           useVirtualThreads="true"
/>
```

Comment: `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` (or any other `java.util.concurrent.Executor` or `TaskExecutor`) affects only `@Async`-tagged Spring beans, discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77825075/how-to-limit-the-number-of-spring-async-tasks-with-virtual-threads-enabled. If you want your Controllers to be invoked on virtual threads you need to configure Tomcat Connector with appropriate Executor - discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77622056/apache-tomcat-with-virtual-thread. Please confirm the above for your case (or come with an MRE) and then more detailed answer could be given.

Comment: @igor.zh We have Tomcat configured properly I believe. I have updated the question with our current server.xml configuration.

Comment: The configuration of Connector you posted works on my example which uses environment identical to what you brought in the description, the Controller gets executed on a virtual thread, Tomcat names it `http-nio-8080-virt-<N>`. Please post your  MRE or a closest to it you could get, alternatively I could place on github my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, virtual threads work in non-Spring Boot Spring MVC applications. If it is a web application to be deployed to a servlet container/web server, like Tomcat, then whether `@Controller` request-handling methods will be executed on virtual or platform thread will depend on configuration of this container.

Like the OP correctly said, as of Tomcat version 10.1.18, Connector's protocol has to be configured with `useVirtualThreads` attribute, like

```
<Connector ...
       useVirtualThreads="true" />
```

This works for any `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint` subclasses, NIO and NIO2 in particular. Note, that configuring

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPoolVirtual" class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardVirtualThreadExecutor"/>
```

is unnecessary, as the `AbstractEndpoint` hardcodes the usage of `org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.VirtualThreadExecutor`, the latter creates the virtual threads with the names `http-nio-<port>-virt-<number>`.

Outside of servlet container/for non-web-app Spring-based applications, as far as Spring is concerned, the usage of virtual threads can be achieved by annotating a Spring Bean method with `@Async`:

```
@Service
public class HomeService {

    @Async
    public void goHome() {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

and invocation of this method will look like

```
@Autowired
private HomeService homeService;

...

homeService.goHome();
```

Async machinery should be properly configured: with `@EnableAsync` annotation to a `@Configuration` class or, if XML configuration is used, like described in [Spring XML equivalent of @EnableAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401640/spring-xml-equivalent-of-enableasync)

If you believe that some of your asynchronous methods should be executed on virtual threads, and some should not, then you could define multiple `org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor`s: one - for virtual threads, another one - for platform ones:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor platformExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor virtualExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    executor.setVirtualThreads(true);
    return executor;
}
```

, then asynchronous methods might look like the following:

```
@Async("virtualExecutor")
public void goHomeVirtually() {
    ...
}

@Async("platformExecutor")
public void goHome() {
    ...
}
```

A full working example can be found in [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/eager-zh/non-spring-boot-mvc-application-with-virtual-threads).