# Using virtual thread in Spring 6 without spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-21, virtual-threads

I want to use virtual thread in my spring application where tomcat is not embedded within the application like in spring boot app.
So to enable virtual thread I added the following configuration.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.core.task.support.TaskExecutorAdapter;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer;

@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class VirtualThreadConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor() {
        return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
        return protocolHandler -> {
            protocolHandler.setExecutor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
        };
    }
}
```

Where do I get the `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer` class?  What dependency needs to be included?

Comment: That class is only packaged as part of the Spring-boot dependency.  There are other stackoverflow post that indicate how to accomplish in a Tomcat non-spring-boot environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847167/virtual-threads-in-spring-mvc-in-non-spring-boot-application

Comment: Your configuration of protocol handler is conceptually correct, but you said you use standalone, non-embedded Tomcat, and you try to configure embedded one.  To configure non-embedded Tomcat, you have to change `Connector` element of its `server.xml`.  Your configuration of `TaskExecutor` is correct, but it will only work for the methods, annotated by `@Async` and properly _advised_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual Threads in Spring MVC in Non-Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847167/virtual-threads-in-spring-mvc-in-non-spring-boot-application)